# Some emails are almost complete jibberish...not sure what is going on

Tags: windows, exchange

One of my end users has a bunch of old emails that look like the below text...I'm not sure how to begin fixing this (or if they can be fixed).

Any help would be appreciated!

html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"> head> meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 12 (filtered medium)"> !--[if !mso]> style> v* url(#default#VML);} o* url(#default#VML);} w* url(#default#VML);} shape url(#default#VML);} /style> ![endif]--> style> !-- /* Font Definitions */ @font-face Calibri; panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;} font-face Tahoma; panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;} /* Style Definitions */ p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal 0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:11.0pt; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";} a:link, span.MsoHyperlink 99; color:blue; text-decoration:underline;} a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed 99; color:purple; text-decoration:underline;} p.MsoAcetate, li.MsoAcetate, div.MsoAcetate 99; mso-style-link:"Balloon Text Char"; margin:0in; margin-bottom:.0001pt; font-size:8.0pt; font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";} span.BalloonTextChar "Balloon Text Char"; mso-style-priority:99; mso-style-link:"Balloon Text"; font-family:"Tahoma","sans-serif";} span.EmailStyle19 personal; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:windowtext;} span.EmailStyle20 personal-reply; font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif"; color:#1F497D;} MsoChpDefault export-only; font-size:10.0pt;} page Section1 8.5in 11.0in; margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;} div.Section1 Section1;} -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's frequently the result of bad MIME headers. The result of this is that the mail client doesn't know how to handle a section, so it reproduces it in straight up text. That's supposed to be an HTML-encoded message, but clearly that specific mail client can't figure that out. There isn't much you can do for that, though those messages may be readable in other mail clients.

Comment: The email was opened in Outloook, what else should I have the user try to open the emails in? I'm not aware of any other clients that have direct Exchange integration.

Comment: Outlook Web Access may give different results. If you have IMAP enabled, Thunderbird may yield different results as well.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to be able to read those messages you could try copying the contents into a text file, editing the header, saving it as *.html and open it with a browser. That doesn't always work as well as it might but I've had fairly good results that way.